# click event is firing asynchronasly

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have a click event attached to an anchor, and I'm using multiple anchors. The user may click these anchors randomly, and each anchor click creates a dynamic UL list. Everything is working fine except when the user clicks the anchors fast, creation of UL list is happening asynchronously. I want the events to be ordered synchronously. Any solution?

Comment: code is very lengthy, I found out what is creating proble. I have two ajax() method.. how to make calls from two different ajax() methods to be synchronous?

Comment: Consider async setting of the ajax() method.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the AJAX calls in jQuery to be Synchronous, check the [manpage](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax) for the `async` parameter definition. Note that **this will lock the browser** for as long as the AJAX call is running.

The other solution would be to execute the second AJAX call in the `success` callback function of the first, hence making one execute after the other. This is ok for 2 calls but gets nasty when it's more.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to chain two method, without making losing async part of it, then I will recommended to check for JQuery [promise](http://api.jquery.com/promise/) . that will help you to queue the results.